# Is there SEQUENCE equvalent in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

In Sql Server and Oracle I can obtain an ID using a [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx). I wanted to know if there is an equivalent in MongoDB. I want to obtain the id first then store the it in multiple places including RDBMS. Is this possible to do?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski objectId is not equivalent to sequence asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though MongoDB doesn't provide an auto-incrementing sequence out of the box, there are all building blocks available and MongoDB documentation provides recommendations on how to implement them: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

I think it is worth noting also, that MongoDB instead embraces the use of natural unique identifiers, or, otherwise - generated [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) (which is not sequenced yet every new instance is unique). That is, for example, if a document is saved without a `_id` assigned to it, DB **client** will automatically generate an ObjectId for it. This functionality is built into all client APIs by default.

If you want to reuse the ObjectId assigned to a new document, there are two options:

- either [grab `_id` field](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_WriteConcernResult_Upserted.htm) value of a newly stored document
- or [generate an ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId_GenerateNewId.htm) yourself and assign it to a `_id` field of a document yourself

Comment: Hello, it does NOT have to be auto-incrementing. I just need to create a id before i insert a record

Comment: Ok, didnt read whole answer. GenerateNewId is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - there is no equivalent for that in Mongo.
Was thinking about server side javascript but to be honest, in this case what I will do is shift this responsibility to application domain, using one of collections as a trace (let say last sequence) - in other words manual sequence function implementation.

Comment: I agree I consider that don't exist an equivalent,  even in Spring data for mongo when I insert a new document acctually Spring generate a uuid as id for me